# Sistema em uma única pasta, com vários BDs

Tags: php, dinâmico

Estou finalizando um sistema online para um gerenciamento de pacientes.
A página (domínio.com.br) tem um sistema de login.

Se eu tiver 3 usuários cadastrados, cada um teria que acessar o seu respectivo banco de dados.

Eu queria saber, se via PHP, eu conseguiria fazer isso.

Comment: Sim, com certeza pode. Mas, porque criar um banco de dados pra cada usuário? Porque não colocar todos no mesmo banco? Não faz sentido. E sobre o cadastro dos usuários, eles seriam cadastrados em arquivos normais ou em um quarto banco de dados?

Comment: Pq cada farmácia tem os seus pacientes, cada paciente tem suas receitas, etc. Acho que ficaria mais organizado.

Comment: Pensei em um BD separado para os usuários. Assim que logasse, pegaria o bd vinculado ao usuário e conectava para carregar os dados da sua farmácia. É assim os seus respectivos pacientes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realmente não é necessário fazer isso criando um banco de dados pra cada usuário. Você pode alocar todos no mesmo banco. Basta saber estruturar as tabelas colocando um identificador em cada linha que referencie a farmácia responsável pelo registro.

No entanto, se você ainda quiser fazer da sua maneira, criando um banco de dados para cada farmácia, é só registrar as credenciais do banco junto com o registro do usuário. Veja a tabela abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No modelo acima, você consegue cadastrar um ou vários usuários para gerenciarem a mesma farmácia.

No momento login, após verificar se o nome de usuário e senha batem com o cadastro, você pega o ID da farmácia correspondente ao usuário e faz um novo SELECT para buscar as credenciais de login do banco de dados da farmácia a qual o usuário pertence. Aí é só abrir uma nova conexão no PHP.

Você também pode imeplementar mais recursos nas tabelas, como por exemplo um nível de permissão pro usuário, pro sistema identificar o que ele pode acessar ou não. Enfim.

Creio que eu tenha sido claro. Qualquer dúvida, só comentar.

Comment: Isso mesmo, era criar um banco de dados para cada farmácia, e não para cada usuário. Obrigado!

Comment: Outra coisa: cada farmácia teria que ter 3 pastas separadamente (receitas, documentos e comprovantes). Tem como setar isso dinamicamente também pelo BD?

Comment: Você fala de pastas de verdade ou de tabelas no banco?

Comment: Pastas de verdade, dentro do FTP.